# How can I permute dimensions in cv::Mat from CxWxH to WxHxC?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

How can I permute dimensions in cv::Mat from CxWxH to WxHxC (Width x Height x Channels)?

I.e. how can I convert Mat:

- from `cv::Mat frame (1000, 1000, CV_8UC3) = cv::imread("image.jpg", -1);`

  with dimesions: **channels, width, height**
- to Mat with dimesions: **width, height, channels**

  `int sizes_inputs[] = { 3, 1000, 1000 };
  cv::Mat out_image(3, sizes_inputs, CV_8UC);`

Is there in OpenCV a ready-made fast function for such a conversion? Or should I implement this algorithm myself?

Comment: You need to do it yourself. If you need to do this for deep learning, you can use the [blob](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d16/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Blob.html) class (as well as the whole dnn module)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to treat the underlying data differently, then you can use `reshape`. The data is stored as `BGRBGRBGR...`.

Otherwise you will have to shuffle the data yourself.
`cv::reshape` and `cv::minChannels` may be handy for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate it. I have not tested the code but something like this should do:

```
cv::Mat frame (1000, 1000, CV_8UC3) = cv::imread("image.jpg", -1);
int sizes_inputs[] = { 3, 1000, 1000 };
cv::Mat out_image(3, sizes_inputs, CV_8UC);

cv::Mat slices[] = {cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC, out_image.ptr()),
                    cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC, out_image.ptr() + 1000*1000),
                    cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC, out_image.ptr() + 1000*1000*2)};
cv::split(frame, slices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer here: [C++ OpenCV transpose/permute image axes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72462193/)

I tried with the following code:

```
cv::Mat a = cv::imread("red.png");
auto b = a.clone();
std::vector<cv::Mat> planes =
{
    cv::Mat(a.rows, a.cols, CV_8U, b.ptr(0)), 
    cv::Mat(a.rows, a.cols, CV_8U, b.ptr(0) + a.rows * a.cols),
    cv::Mat(a.rows, a.cols, CV_8U, b.ptr(0) + a.rows * a.cols * 2)
};
cv::split(a, planes);
```

By watching the value of a and b, the buffer seemed to be correct.
[image]
[image]